# Bootstrap carousel: how to use more slides?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

How can I use Bootstrap to make such carousel? Not one by one slider, but like the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

click the link to Check this one ttp://euasia.com.sg 
the effect you wanted (under the text choose your dream destination from the above url) 
and It's using caroufredsel plugin. very easy to use.

```
<script>
    $('#countryHomeIcon').carouFredSel({
        items               : 6,
        scroll : {
            items           : 4,
            duration        : 1000,
            pauseOnHover    : true
        },
        height:190,
        width:190,
        play:false,
        prev:'.prev',
        next:'.next',
        responsive: true,
        auto: false
    });    

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the bootstrap carousel plugin but you can use other carousel plugins like [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified#example1) or [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.